# OOZIE : Connection exception has occurred [ java.net.ConnectException Connection refused (Connection refused) ]

Tags: hadoop, httpurlconnection, cloudera, oozie, oozie-workflow

I'm trying to execute Oozie job with the help of 
URL: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/apache-oozie/9781449369910/ch05.html

While executing 
`oozie job -run -config target/example/job.properties`

Getting error as :

```
Connection exception has occurred [ java.net.ConnectException Connection refused (Connection refused) ]. Trying after 1 sec. Retry count = 1
Connection exception has occurred [ java.net.ConnectException Connection refused (Connection refused) ]. Trying after 2 sec. Retry count = 2
Connection exception has occurred [ java.net.ConnectException Connection refused (Connection refused) ]. Trying after 4 sec. Retry count = 3
Connection exception has occurred [ java.net.ConnectException Connection refused (Connection refused) ]. Trying after 8 sec. Retry count = 4
Error: IO_ERROR : java.io.IOException: Error while connecting Oozie server. No of retries = 4. Exception = Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Any idea; why connection is getting refused?

Answer (score 2):

It is not able to connect to the Oozie server from Oozie client (command line). Find the Oozie server url and do one of the following:

- Set (export) the Oozie server as environment variable `export OOZIE_URL=http://hostname:11000/oozie`
- Use the `-oozie` parameter into the oozie command. `oozie job -oozie http://hostname:11000/oozie -run -config target/example/job.properties`

Comment: # oozie job -oozie http://hostname:11000 -run -config target/example/job.properties
java.io.IOException: configuration is not specified
        at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.getConfiguration(OozieCLI.java:794)
        at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.jobCommand(OozieCLI.java:1033)
        at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.processCommand(OozieCLI.java:664)
        at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.run(OozieCLI.java:617)
        at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.main(OozieCLI.java:218)
configuration is not specified

Comment: @PawanMude I have updated the commands.  You need to replace the host name into them and port on which oozie server is running.

Comment: Thanks @YoungHobbit ; still i'm getting error as : Connection exception has occurred [ java.net.ConnectException Connection refused ]. Trying after 1 sec. Retry count = 1
Connection exception has occurred [ java.net.ConnectException Connection refused ]. Trying after 2 sec. Retry count = 2
Connection exception has occurred [ java.net.ConnectException Connection refused ]. Trying after 4 sec. Retry count = 3

Comment: If I run command  sudo -u oozie /usr/lib/oozie/bin/ooziedb.sh upgrade -run it gives me error as  Validate DB Connection
DONE
Check DB schema exists

Error: DB schema does not exist

Stack trace for the error was (for debug purposes):
--------------------------------------
java.lang.Exception: DB schema does not exist
        at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.validateDBSchema(OozieDBCLI.java:941)
        at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.upgradeDB(OozieDBCLI.java:200)
        at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.run(OozieDBCLI.java:132)

Comment: Can you check that, oozie server is in the running state?

Comment: Yes oozie server is running. Now I'm able to fix DB schema error. Error: E0501 : E0501: Could not perform authorization operation, Call From #hostname# to localhost:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused