# Connection refused Error while invoking oozie from Cloudera VM CDH3

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, workflow, scheduler, oozie

I am new to oozie. Can someone please help me? I am trying to invoke oozie from vmware using below commands:

```
oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config job.properties -run
oozie job -oozie http://localhost.localdomain:11000/oozie -config job.properties -run
```

But I am facing below error:

```
Error: IO_ERROR : java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Below are the property file details:

```
cat job.properties
nameNode=hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020
jobTracker=localhost.localdomain:8021
queueName=default
weatherRoot=training
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/usr/${weatherRoot}/oozie
outputDir=/usr/training/oozie/output
```

Have observed below details in oozie-env.sh script:

```
export OOZIE_HTTP_PORT=11000
export OOZIE_HTTP_HOSTNAME=`hostname -f`
export OOZIE_BASE_URL="http://${OOZIE_HTTP_HOSTNAME}:${OOZIE_HTTP_PORT}/oozie"
```

Could someone please help me? Thanks for your help in Advance.

Comment: Could you post a longer stacktrace?

Comment: Hi. I looked at /var/log/messages file, but couldn't get any information. Can you please let me know where I can get stacktrace details?

Comment: I mean when you run the jobs, I expect you get more output than just the single line of Connection refused message?

Comment: I have just got Connection refused error only.(Error: IO_ERROR : java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused). No further detail on my console.

Comment: this will help to resolve your issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839025/oozie-connection-exception-has-occurred-java-net-connectexception-connection